# Installing Cartaro using Acquia Dev Desktop and link it with GeoServer and PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, boundless-suite, cartaro

How do I configure GeoServer and PostGIS so that I don't get the following error when installing Cartaro using the Acquia Dev Desktop. I am just installing Cartaro locally for testing, or else how can OpenGeoSuite be installed with Cartaro?

[image: screenshot of the error message when installing cartaro]

Comment: Oh and remember I have OpenGeoSuite installed already

Answer (score 1):

Acquia Dev Desktop is meant to work with MySQL. and Cartaro requires PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

Cartaro prerequisites related to PostGIS and GeoServer could be found in the Cartaro install documentation.

Cartaro is fully compatible with OpenGeoSuite, not requiring additional steps besides those given in the Cartaro install documentation.

Cartaro install has not been fully documented/tested with Windows. You can find more help installing Cartaro on Windows in this video: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QuSOAG59jI0

Anyway, if you just want to test Cartaro, you can play with it on demo.cartaro.org or **install the OSGeo Virtual machine** from: http://live.osgeo.org/en/quickstart/virtualization_quickstart.html